# C# compiler (csc.exe) memory overflow compiling nested types and Linq

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio, csc

I found one unpleasant behavior developing with Visual Studio. It was hanging my machine while compiling C#.

I have reduced behavior to the next minimal source code

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace memoryOverflowCsharpCompiler {

    class SomeType { public decimal x; }

    class TypeWrapper : Dictionary<int,
                        Dictionary<int,
                        Dictionary<int, SomeType [] []>>> {

        public decimal minimumX() {
            return base.Values.Min(a =>
                      a.Values.Min(b =>
                      b.Values.Min(c =>
                      c       .Sum(d =>
                      d       .Sum(e => e.x)))));
        }
    }
}
```

Compiling with

```
PROMPT> csc source.cs

    *** BANG! overflow memory usage (up to ~3G)

PROMPT> csc /?
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 12.0.30501.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
...
```

(using Windows 8.1 Pro N x64; `csc` compiler process is running with 32bits)

sightly modifications don't produce this behavior (eg. changing `decimal` by `int`, reducing one nested level, ...), performing a big `Select` then reducing, works fine

Explicit workaround:

```
            return base.Values.SelectMany(a =>
                      a.Values.SelectMany(b =>
                      b.Values.Select    (c =>
                      c.       Sum       (d =>
                      d.       Sum       (e => e.x))))).Min();
```

Although this explicit workaround exists, it not guaranteed that this behavior will not occur again.

What's wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Out of interest, have you tried this with the VS2015 preview? It would be interesting to know if it's fixed in Roslyn.

Comment: This code has several things that make it hard to infer the types: 1) Implicit conversions 2) Many overloads 3) nested lambdas. If you try hard enough, you can encode NP complete SAT problems into these, so the compiler can't solve all overload resolution+type inferrence problems efficiently. But I don't know why your example is so bad.

Comment: @JonSkeet Any volunteers? (I can't) I have searched about that but not found :(

Comment: @CodesInChaos but changing `decimal` by `int` works (with same level of 1), 2) and 3)

Comment: Will give it a try when I get a chance.

Comment: It seems that generic type resolution fails in that case. Specifying type argument explicitly fixes compilation problem

Comment: BTW on x64 I was able to compile it normally (but memory usage was around 2,5GB), but nesting it one more time caused overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that generic type resolution fails in that case. Changing from `decimal` to `int` works by chance. If you increase nesting level, than you'll see that it also fails for int. On my x64 machine this code compiles for both `int` and `decimal` and uses around 2.5GB of memory, but increasing nesting level results in overflow when memory usage growing to aroung 4GB.

Specifying type argument explicitly allows to compile code:

```
class TypeWrapper : Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, SomeType[][]>>>>
{
    public decimal minimumX()
    {
        return base.Values
            .Min<Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, SomeType[][]>>>, decimal>(a => a.Values
                .Min<Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, SomeType[][]>>, decimal>(b => b.Values
                    .Min<Dictionary<int, SomeType[][]>, decimal>(c => c.Values
                        .Min(d => d
                            .Sum(e => e.Sum(f => f.x))
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
    }
}
```

Also compiler works when you reduce nesting by introducing local variable:

```
class TypeWrapper : Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, SomeType[][]>>>>
{
    public decimal minimumX()
    {
        Func<Dictionary<int, SomeType[][]>, decimal> inner = (Dictionary<int, SomeType[][]> c) => c.Values
                        .Min(d => d
                            .Sum(e => e.Sum(f => f.x))
                        );

        return base.Values
            .Min(a => a.Values
                .Min(b => b.Values
                    .Min(inner)
                )
            );
    }
}
```